# Hadoop - java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, hadoop, port-number

My Hadoop installation was working fine, till I tried to change the port numbers. Now, when I run any hadoop program, I get:

```
java.net.BindException: Problem binding to localhost/127.0.0.1:9010 : Address already in use
```

9010 is the port number of the JobTracker defined in `conf/mapred-site.xml`. I tried to change it, but I still get the same error.

I even tried to stop Hadoop through `bin/stop-all.sh` and then check if the port is used through `netstat -nl | grep 9010` and found nothing.

Any help to get past this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Have you defines two hadoop services to run on port 9010? (say both the JT and NN). Try and start dfs first and then mapred second (there are scripts in the bin folder to do this). If you're still having problems, post some more context around the error - which service is failing to start?

Comment: Well, it turned out that the problem was with the code I was running, other hadoop programs run fine. I was searching for fixing hadoop conf files, never thought the error might come from my code. Now I'll debug it, thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Hadoop 1.2.1 deployed on MAC OS X 10.10.

I pulled my hair off and at the end it was because of a stuck service. I restarted my iMAC and it worked fine.

After that the DataNode didn't start. I removed everything in the `/data` directory specified in the `core-site.xml` under property `<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>` and it worked fine.

I know this is an old post. But, I replied to share the experience.

Comment: How did you remove everything

Comment: Do it in this order:
1- bin/Stop-all.sh
2- Go the directory specified in "hadoop.tmp.dir" and do "rm -rf *"
3- Reformat the namenode using **bin/hadoop namenode -format**
4- bin/start-all.sh